# Android Stock Calendar or android.content.ContentResolver.query() ignores selectionArgs

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor

I am fetching events from `Stock Google Calendar` with the unofficial API on older devices. Now i am refactoring the code to use `selection` and `selectionArgs` of `android.content.ContentResolver.query()` instead of only manually binding `selection` (which produces valid SQL and works on my test devices [2.2 and 2.3.3] without problems).

**Problem:** If I bind arguments immediately (example: `deleted = 0`) my test application returns the expected events but when Android binds (example: `deleted = ?` with `String[] { "0" }` no events are returned. What is the reason for ignoring `selectionArgs`?

LogCat shows no errors.

---

**Example (Expected)**

```
STATIC: cursor=225
DYNAMIC: cursor=255
```

255 events are returned because my calendar has 255 events occurring this year.

**Example (Test case)**

Tested on: Motorola Milestone, CyanogenMod 7 (Android 2.3.3).

```
STATIC: cursor=225
DYNAMIC: cursor=0
```

I assume (but hope that I am doing something wrong) that Android or the calendar application fails at binding. I found a bug report with a similar problem, but I am not sure if the calendar application is affected: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4467

**Code**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Related bugs?
 *
 *   - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4467
 */
public class CalendarCursorTestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Calendar begin = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                 end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        String uriPrefix = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 ? "content://com.android.calendar" : "content://calendar";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPrefix + "/instances/when/" + begin.getTimeInMillis() + "/" + end.getTimeInMillis());

        String[] projection = null;
        String sortOrder = null;

        // test static - log() returns: STATIC: cursor=225 => 225 events found
        {
            String selection = "deleted = 0";
            String[] selectionArgs = null;

            log("STATIC: ", getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder));
        }

        // test dynamic - log() returns: DYNAMIC: cursor=0 => no events found (!)
        {
            String selection = "deleted = ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "0" };

            log("DYNAMIC: ", getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder));
        }
    }


    public void log (String title, Cursor c) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), String.format(
            "%s cursor=%s", title, c == null ? "null" : c.getCount()));
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like the `query` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.3_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#CalendarProvider2.handleInstanceQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder%2Clong%2Clong%2Cjava.lang.String[]%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) simply ignores your selectionArgs

Comment: and it's fixed in [Android 4.0.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#1020)(see `combine` part) - maybe before.

Comment: @zapl Please write a short answer so i am able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CalendarProvider seems to have a bug here.

The implementation of `query` simply ignores the user supplied `selectionArgs` parameter.

If you compare the implementation in [Android 2.3.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.3_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#CalendarProvider2.handleInstanceQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder%2Clong%2Clong%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) and [Android 4.0.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarProvider2.java#1020) you'll notice that they added the `selectionArgs` as parameter and build a `combine` of their own and the user supplied ones.

The bug was fixed here: [Support cleanup of Calendar.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_calendarprovider/commit/2ce7955da7dffec7819ed38be85e72df8a6f33dc)